# Optimize bundle.js file size

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, bundling-and-minification

Below is the webpack config code and it's size is around 6.2 MB. In production mode it looks more time load the signin page url and from second time onwards it looks good , the problem with first time and need suggestion to reduce the bundle.js file size

### webpack.base.js

```
module.exports = {
    //Running babel to every file
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        'react',
                        'stage-0',
                        ['env', { targets: { browsers: ['last 2 versions'] } }]
                    ]
                }
            }, {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use:[
                    {
                        loader: "style-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "less-loader"
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|otf)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
            }

        ]
    }//end module
}
```

### webpack.client.js:

```
const config = {
    entry: './src/client/client.js',

    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
    }
};

module.exports = merge(baseConfig, config)
```

### webpack.server.js:

```
const server_config = {
    //letting webapck know that this bundle is created for node server.
    target: 'node',

    entry: './src/server/server.js',

    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
    },
    externals: [webpackNodeExternals()],
    node:{
        __dirname:false
    }
};

module.exports = merge(baseConfig, server_config);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I optimize webpack. You can view my full config [here](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/webpack.config.js)

First you need to run webpack production mode when you want to build in production

```
webpack -p --mode=production
```

Below is minial config

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({ // minify js file
                cache: true,
                parallel: true,
                sourceMap: false,
                extractComments: 'all',
                uglifyOptions: {
                    compress: true,
                    output: null
                }
            }),
            new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({ // minify css
                cssProcessorOptions: {
                    safe: true,
                    discardComments: {
                        removeAll: true,
                    },
                },
            })
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CompressionPlugin({ // gzip js and css 
            test: /\.(js|css)/
        }),
        new UglifyJsPlugin(), // uglify js
        new WebpackShellPlugin({
            onBuildStart: ['echo "Starting postcss command"'],
            onBuildEnd: ['postcss --dir wwwroot/dist wwwroot/dist/*.css'] // uglify css using postcss
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            minimize: true,
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: ["babel-loader", "eslint-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
                loader: "file-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|ttf|otf|eot|woff2|svg)$/i,
                loader: "file-loader"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```